# Modify sidebar component based on content section component in Vue

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-loader

Here is my template section:

```
<template>
        <!-- START Home.vue section -->
        <div class="container-fluid" v-if="user.authenticated">
            <!-- START Sidebar.vue section -->
            <sidebar-component></sidebar-component>
            <!-- END Sidebar.vue section -->

            <div class="main-container">
                <!-- START Nav.vue section -->
                <nav-component></nav-component>
                <!-- END Nav.vue section -->

                <!-- START Content Section -->
                <router-view></router-view>
                <!-- END Content Section -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END Home.vue section -->
    </template>
```

Clearly it has 3 components: NavComponent,SidebarComponent, Main component area that will be replaced by the routed component.

I have another component `ApplicationList` component that when will replace the `router-view` section of above template, is supposed to cause the sidebar component to behave differently(say for example sidebar becomes hidden or its background becomes red).

So how do I do it?

Comment: In your router view you have differennrt compoonents that will be place depending on the path you are on,,,so for each component you want the sidebar to get displayed differently,,,,is that what you wamt

Answer (score 0):

1. Install https://github.com/vuejs/vuex-router-sync . It will give you your current route state in your Vuex.
2. In your `<sidebar-component>` just refer to `this.$store.state.route.name` (or path, or whatever you need) and use it in your `v-if` or some `watch` .

This is the easiest and most scalable solution to handle changes in components based on current route in application.

Hope it helps.